# Push changes to another branch in github

Tags: git, github

Silly question, but i need help.

There are two branches in the same repository in git-hub. A and B.I have cloned the branch A, i made some changes and now I want to push the changes to branch B.With 'git status' i can see that my branch is up-to-date with 'origin/A'.
Should i add and commit the changes and then just 'push' to 'origin/B'?

What can I do to push the changes to the correct branch(B) and not A?I don't want to replace anything in the A branch.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question - are A and B branches or repositories?

Comment: Sorry.I changed the question.A and B are Branches

Comment: Did you add your changes to branch A yet or not?

Comment: I didn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

- switch on branch `B`:

  ```
  git checkout B
  ```
- merge `A` in `B`

  ```
  git merge A
  ```
- push the changes

  ```
  git push origin B
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to do git push origin frombranch:tobranch

EDIT after looking at your clarifying comments:
`git checkout branch-b;`
`git merge branch-a`

assuming you have `origin\branch-a` and is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If A is up to date, and is your origin, checkout branch B and just do git merge origin and B will be updated with all A's latest changes.  If you want to check first before merging origin (A), do git fetch origin then do git log -p HEAD..origin to see the changes you are going to merge.